# jQuery UI sortable and live() click problem -- need to click twice after sorting for click to register

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table I'm using jQuery UI's "sortable" on. In the table, I have rows consisting of a "drag handle" to grab and reorder the table, and cells with clickable items, like this:

```
<table id="test-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="handle"><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" /></td>
        <td class="clickycell"><a href="#">Testing 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="handle"><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" /></td>
        <td class="clickycell"><a href="#">Testing 2</a></td></td>
    <tr>
        <td class="handle"><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" /></td>
        <td class="clickycell"><a href="#">Testing 3</a></td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my code, I make the table sortable, and also use jQuery's `live()` to bind a click event to the clickable items, like this:

```
$(function() {
    /*
       Using live() because in my real code table rows are dynamically added.
       However, if I use click() instead, as in the commented-out code, it works
       fine, without any need to click twice.

    */
    // $(".clickycell a").click(function() {
    $(".clickycell a").live('click', function() {
        alert("Successful click");
        return false;
    });
    $("#test-table tbody").sortable({
        handle: "td.handle", /* Use the draggy handle to move, not the whole row */
        cursor: "move"
    });
});
```

I'm using `live()` because rows can be dynamically added to the table in the real code.

My problem is this: if I click on any of the clickable items before sorting, they work fine. After the user drags the rows to reorder them, though, I have to click *twice* for a click to register. After that second click, the clickable items go back to "normal", needing only one click, until the next time rows are dragged around.

If I use `click()` rather than `live()` -- as in the commented-out code -- then a single-click works fine at all times, but I'd rather use `live()`, as I said. And I'm curious as to why it's not working.

There's [a live jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/U6sgM/4/). Try dragging a row into a different position, then clicking on any of the "Testing..." links. In Firefox, at least, I need to click twice to get the "Successful click" alert.

Any ideas?

Comment: Chrome doesn't have a problem.

Comment: I verified the problem in FF, but it's a strange bug!  Unless someone answers here with what I'm missing, you may want to file a bug report.

Comment: @Stephen Interesting, thanks; might indeed be a jQuery bug then. The problem also shows up in IE6, which is the only other browser I have available at work (don't ask!)

Comment: Interestingly, after I finish a drag, I can click once on the drag-handle and then on the link and it works.  So it seems there is a problem with the click event bubbling or something.  I would guess that it's a bug with jQuery UI dealing with the .live method, not jQuery.

Comment: Now I'm fit to be tied.  Look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/A9HCH/3/ although I've left out the anchor selector, the code still works as though it is there in Chrome.  Also, when I try to use `.children('a')` on the td element, nothing works.

Comment: @Stephen Well, I think I'd expect the click still to work without the anchor selector, as that would just make the table cell clickable, rather than the anchor. Can't quite see what you mean about the children(), though...

Comment: @Stephen Have played and now see what you mean about .children('a'). Odd that .find('a') works, and also that .children('a') works for anything *except* live()... My head hurts now!

Comment: @Stephen Ahh -- interesting; looks like there's a [very similar open bug in jQuery UI](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4953), though it only describes the problem happening in IE. I would add details to the bug, but jQuery UI's trac isn't letting me, because (a) it thinks my comment is spam, and (b) the consequent reCAPTCHA form doesn't work (no words in the box), so I can't get past it! D'oh.

Comment: @Stephen Incidentally, if you want to submit an answer, I pretty much did what you said and updated that jQuery UI bug report -- definitely looks like you were right and it's a bug in sortable. Damn it. I've worked around it by manually adding click() event handlers where appropriate instead of using live()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate to end with the answer "[It is a bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4953)," but I guess sometimes that happens.  Maybe I'll dust off my GitHub login and fork it to see if I can track it down and discover a fix.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same issue with "live" and sortable when I found your post (delegate has the same problem as well). To follow up on the observation @Stephen made about clicking on the drag handle once before an item's click handler bound with live works without having to click twice... I've successfully used this workaround. For a hack, I don't find it too offensive.

```
$('table.demo tbody').sortable({
    handle: 'td.drag',
    stop: function(e,ui){
        $('td.drag', ui.item).click();
    }
});
```

I'm just issuing a click call to the drag handler as soon as the drag is complete, and now other items (in my row) that I have bound with live do not require clicking on twice.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't verify this, as I've moved on to something different now, but +1 for adding the answer; hopefully it'll help someone else!